# Making sense of Scattering of Impulsive Gravitational Waves

Tags: general-relativity, scattering, gravitational-waves

Consider the space-time diagram of [KP-wave](https://www.nature.com/articles/229185a0) as shown below:
[image]

We see that two transverse plane fronted GW waves intersect at the point ($u,v$)=(0,0). The curvature comes with a delta function, except in the forward light cone region (marked as "Curved") where there is a finite jump in curvature.

The model seems counter-intuitive, given that how a single impulsive wave can affect transverse null trajectories : one can expect a shift / memory effect on null trajectories/planes induced by the impulsive wave (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(85)90525-5)). Thus, intuitively one can guess that when two impulsive waves cross each other, both of them will be shifted due to each other's delta function type curvature: they should not cross each other at a particular point in a meaningful sense. I have two possible space-time diagrams if we include this effect, but they are heuristic and qualitatively different from the diagram shown above (which I'll add sometime later).

Thus, my question is if this model (KP-wave) is an accurate description of collision of waves. Or is this the only possible way to model such event? It seems to me that highly energetic waves can't collide at a particular point due to the memory effect but I do not have a rigorous explanation for this.

Comment: You are conflating two types of solutions. The planar waves that are colliding in Khan–Penrose are different from shock waves of Dray–'t Hooft. The former do not depend on planar coordinates $(x,y)$ and have diverging “energy” (with constant surface density), while the latter are localized and asymptotically flat.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you, so that clarifies it. Are there solutions for what happens when two Dray-t' Hooft type shock waves collide with one another? Because those solutions seem more physically meaningful.

Comment: Sure, for example [Giddings & Rychkov](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409131).

Comment: Thank you for the article. I was thinking of gravitational collapse model using such waves where only apparent horizons are formed. This seems to be thr right article to begin with